# Meteor dependent select

Tags: javascript, html, meteor

I need to implement 2 dependent selects in my meteor app. I am new with web development in general and very new with meteor. However I have done something that works but I would like to know if that is the correct way or if there is any other better way to do it. Why I am wondering this is because I have seen some code on the web which I can understand very well yet so I prefer to do it as I think it should be.

The selects are one with car brands and the second one with the models of the selected brand.

I am using the Session in meteor 1.3 (although I've read a little bit that there is something call reactive vars which can be used as well).

Please do not take into account security issues for now.

Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
const VEHICLE_MODELS = "vehicleModels";

function setVehicleModels(vehicleModels){
    Session.set(VEHICLE_MODELS, vehicleModels);    
}

function getVehicleModels(){
    return Session.get(VEHICLE_MODELS);    
}

Template.startJob.events({
    'change #carBrands': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var selectedBrand = $("#carBrands").val();
        var vehicleData = Vehicles.findOne({"make":selectedBrand})
        setVehicleModels(vehicleData.models);        
    }
});

Template.startJob.helpers({
    carBrands(){
        return Vehicles.find();
    },
    carModels(){
        return getVehicleModels();        
    }    
});

<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="carBrands" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                            Make
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select id="carBrands" class="form-control select2">
                                <option value="">Select a brand...</option>
                                {{#each carBrands}}
                                    <option value="{{make}}">{{make}}</option>
                                {{/each}}                                
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="carModels" class="col-sm-2 control-label">
                            Model
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select id="carModels" class="form-control select2">
                                <option value="">Select a model...</option>
                                {{#each carModels}}
                                    <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
                                {{/each}}                                
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Did you place this in form in the template (startJob)?

Comment: @AnkushRishi Yes I did. I just didn't want to put the whole code of the form. `<form class="form-horizontal">`

Answer (score 0):

The classic pattern for this in Meteor is to use a `Session` variable which is set by an event and drives the data context of the dependent menu. This simplifies your code a tiny bit since only one `Session` variable (or alternatively a reactive variable) is required.

```
Template.startJob.events({
    'change #carBrands': function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var selectedBrand = $("#carBrands").val();
        var vehicleData = Vehicles.findOne({ make: selectedBrand })
        Session.set('brandId', selectedBrand._id);         
    }
});

Template.startJob.helpers({
    carBrands(){
        return Vehicles.find();
    },
    carModels(){
        return VehicleModels.find({ brandId: Session.get('brandId') });        
    }    
});
```

With no changes to your html.

Comment: Hi. If you see my code, I have one collection only! And yes, I'm using Session. Thanks. It looks like what I did is alright!